# Setup SD Card Reader on Debian 10

Tags: debian, kernel, drivers, sd-card

I want to use the sd card reader on my ASUS UX501VW-FY144T. Via hw-probe ([link](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=3a70b17a13)) one can see that the sd card is a Alcor Micro AU6621, which isn't configured correct.

[image: hw-probe]

So I updated to the kernel version 5.10.:

```
 ~ cat /proc/version                                                                           
Linux version 5.10.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-8 (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.31.1) #1 SMP Debian 5.10.13-1~bpo10+1 (2021-02-11)
```

Now there should be support for this card reader according to [github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/2c85ebc57b3e1817b6ce1a6b703928e113a90442/include/linux/alcor_pci.h).

But on insertion nothing happens. `dmesg` prints nothing and `lsusb`, `lsblk`, `lscpi` don't list the sd card reader.

UPDATE:

Output of `lspci -nn -d 1aea::`:

`02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro Device [1aea:6621]`

Output of `grep -e MISC_ALCOR_PCI -e MMC_ALCOR -e MFD_CORE -e MMC /boot/config-5.10.*`:

```
CONFIG_PCI_MMCONFIG=y
CONFIG_MMCONF_FAM10H=y
# CONFIG_MISC_ALCOR_PCI is not set
CONFIG_MFD_CORE=y
# MMC/SDIO DVB adapters
CONFIG_MMC=m
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK=m
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_MINORS=256
# CONFIG_MMC_TEST is not set
# MMC/SD/SDIO Host Controller Drivers
# CONFIG_MMC_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI=m
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_IO_ACCESSORS=y
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_PCI=m
CONFIG_MMC_RICOH_MMC=y
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_ACPI=m
# CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_PLTFM is not set
CONFIG_MMC_WBSD=m
CONFIG_MMC_TIFM_SD=m
# CONFIG_MMC_SPI is not set
CONFIG_MMC_SDRICOH_CS=m
CONFIG_MMC_CB710=m
CONFIG_MMC_VIA_SDMMC=m
CONFIG_MMC_VUB300=m
CONFIG_MMC_USHC=m
# CONFIG_MMC_USDHI6ROL0 is not set
CONFIG_MMC_REALTEK_PCI=m
CONFIG_MMC_REALTEK_USB=m
CONFIG_MMC_CQHCI=m
# CONFIG_MMC_HSQ is not set
CONFIG_MMC_TOSHIBA_PCI=m
# CONFIG_MMC_MTK is not set
CONFIG_MMC35240=m
# CONFIG_PHY_INTEL_LGM_EMMC is not set
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!
Luke

Comment: @binarysta `lspci -nn -d 1aea::` might be a better command to achieve the same thing.

Comment: thanks to @telcoM, please provide `lspci -nn -d 1aea::` output.

Comment: Also, the output of `grep -e MISC_ALCOR_PCI -e MMC_ALCOR -e MFD_CORE -e MMC /boot/config-5.10.*` should indicate if the driver and its dependencies are available in the kernel configuration or not.

Comment: @telcoM thx, added!

Comment: @binarysta thx, added!

Answer (score 1):

```
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro Device [1aea:6621]
```

According to the PCI vendor and product IDs, this is the card reader. The `lspci` command just does not have a product name for it yet. You could get the PCI device ID database updated by running `sudo /usr/sbin/update-pciids`, but it will only allow the device to be identified by product name in the `lspci` listing: it will have no effect for actual hardware support.

```
# CONFIG_MISC_ALCOR_PCI is not set
```

This indicates the driver for the card reader's bus interface is not enabled in the kernel configuration. If it was enabled as a module, you'd see `CONFIG_MISC_ALCOR_PCI=m` instead. And since this is a dependency for the actual card reader driver (`CONFIG_MMC_ALCOR`), the kernel configurator is not even allowing to select the card reader driver unless its bus interface is enabled first, and so the `CONFIG_MMC_ALCOR` line does not appear at all.

The other dependencies seem to be already available as modules.

You might have to compile your own, very slightly customized kernel package, using the backport kernel's configuration (at `/boot/config-5.10.*`) as a starting point, and just change it to set the two above-mentioned options to be built as modules.

Note that if your system uses UEFI, you might need to disable Secure Boot in order to be able to boot custom kernels without signing them yourself. Once your custom kernel boots successfully with Secure Boot disabled, you can then work towards satisfying the Secure Boot requirements and re-enabling Secure Boot, if you wish.

(If you are not already familiar with it, the kernel build procedure is enough of a challenge without adding Secure Boot to the mix. One step at a time.)

Comment: Can you please be more explicit. I would like to follow your advice but I have no clue what to do exactly: So I would (1) disable secure boot, (2) "set the two above-mentioned options to be built as modules" HOW?? and then (3) "compile your own, very slightly customized kernel package" HOW??.

Comment: (1) usually in your BIOS settings (details depend on hardware model), (2) make a copy of the `/boot/config-*` file of your current kernel, edit it to change the `# CONFIG_MISC_ALCOR_PCI is not set` line to `CONFIG_MISC_ALCOR_PCI=m` and add the line `CONFIG_MMC_ALCOR=m`, then use the modified file as the configuration for the new kernel you'll build; but (3) is quite a large topic with a lot of guides on the net: make sure you find an up-to-date one.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this.